# Placing text from one cell between certain characters of another sentence

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, concatenate

Is it possible to take a word from one cell and place it in between certain characters/words of another cell? (Obviously, I can do this one time but I need to do the same thing multiple times)

For example:

I need to take the words "Bulk Organic Alfalfa Seeds" from cell and place

in between the characters like "><" in another cell

Any help would be really really great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**cell B1:** **`=">"&A1&"<"`**

[image]